# React dummy component styles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

When writing a dummy reactjs component, how do we decide on these css issues(**should these controlled by dummy component itself or always by the container?**)

- the size of the dummy component, should it be fixed(eg. width: 20px) or flexible(eg. width: 100%, or even just depend on the number of children)
- position of dummy component, for example, if it were a "header component" that is usually fixed to the top of your screen, should I write css inside the dummy header so that it always automatically appear at the top, or let the container decide?

And also, if a container were to decide the style on its dummy child, what's the recommended way to pass the style? (is it something like `<Dummy className="some style in defined container" />` ?) or some other way?

Thanks a lot in advance!